# Why does C# compile to the same size even if I use a smaller datatype?

Tags: c#, filesize

I did a little test, because I wanted to see the difference in file size between sbyte and an int, but when I compile the file to .exe, it's 4kb for both. Why is this happening? I was fascinated that by people who make 4kb games in java, but a hello world app is 4kb in c#.

Comment: A smaller datatype affects the data size, not the code size.

Comment: @RaymondChen   So using sbyte compared to int only uses less space in memory? Not storage? But even then, why is a tiny hello world program 4kb?

Comment: Because there  is a lot of overhead to set up the programm, like loading screen access infrastructure.. Also: It is not so easy to find a hd that allocates less than 4k for anything..

Comment: @TaW           Ok, I suppose that makes sense, but java doesn't seem to be nearly as big, I thought c# and java were pretty similar.

Comment: They are not really similar even as languages. But: The thing you are looking at here is the way runtime libs are treated and there is not really much similarity..

Comment: Why does it cost 0,70 € to mail a tiny letter that says "Hello world"? Shouldn't it cost a lot less since it's just two words?

Comment: The exe file for managed code is a [PE file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly-format), and it has a lot of different sections and padding. For managed apps the actual "code" (IL) is a sub-part of the file, and for small apps it is a very small part of the file. Because of padding the IL size can vary while the overall file size remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very generally speaking, program's code tells CPU what to do - how much memory to allocate, what to put in the allocated memory, how to make decisions based on what's in the memory cells, and so on.

The length of the program does not depend on the amount of memory it allocates at run time, in the same way the two statements

```
allocate 100 1-byte units
```

and

```
allocate 500 4-byte units
```

use the same number of characters.

The difference comes at run-time, though: the first statement allocates 100 bytes, while the second one allocates 2,000 bytes. This difference does not reflect on the size of the statements *describing* the allocation.

Comment: Thanks, I feel like a bit of an idiot, but I don't understand why a hello world program in c# would take up 4kb and in java it would be much less.

Comment: @J.Czekaj Java and C# use very different structure for classes and assemblies. A lot of bytes in your compiled C# "hello world" program does not come from your C# code - the compiler adds it to make it easier to load and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things - if you compile to 64 bit, data types by default are 64 bit aligned. Which is 8 bytes. So much for memory.

But in your case, actually, you do not change anything.

Int32 is as long as Int16 (Actually it is System.Int16, fully type name, actually even more complex, but let's ignore that for the moment). And your code contains type names as strings. While you made the variable smaller, you did not change a byte in code length actually.

Comment: So the file size isn't determined by how much storage variables take up, it's determined just by the amount of characters in the code? But why would it be 4kb for a hello world program, when in java it would be much smaller?

Comment: Likely because dll's are not class files. You do know that the windows file system alloccates space per standard in 4kb increments? A  1kb file saves nothing. You would have to loo up the file spec of an exe to se what takes up the space.